# How can i extend an Angular app without change the original code, like an add-on?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to extend an application built into Angular, but I don't want to change the application files, I want to create an external file that interacts with this application and run few more actions on each page. Example:

1. When Route: /projects
2. Original App: Runs the code to open this page
   (no changes here)
3. My App: Runs at the end of the original action and
   add more details on this page.

Can i implement such thing with Angular? Would you provide me an example?

This is what i tried until now:

First i tried to interact with the original app module, works, but it replaces the original controller with mine.

```
angular.module("ac.system")
    .config(["$routeProvider", function($routeProvider) {
        console.log('routeProvider');
        $routeProvider
            .when('/projects', {
                template: '',
                controller: 'ProjectsPage'
            });
    }])
    .controller('ProjectsPage', ['$http', function ($http) {
        console.log('ProjectsPage');
    }]);
```

Then I tried creating my own module with the same route, it does nothing.

```
angular.module("myAddOn", [])
    .config(["$routeProvider", function($routeProvider) {
        console.log('routeProvider');
        $routeProvider
            .when('/projects', {
                template: '',
                controller: 'ProjectsPage'
            });
    }])
    .controller('ProjectsPage', ['$http', function ($http) {
        console.log('ProjectsPage');
    }]);
```

Comment: So you want the same route to go to 2 different controllers?

Comment: No matter what, you'll have to add routes to the `app.js` or modify code in the original to call your code.  We can't really help you without seeing an example of the code you'd like to call into your code.

Comment: Yes, that's the basic point. I've tried using the same module from the original app, but it replaces the controller, than i tried to create my module and route the same path, but it does nothing.